# How can I map _ (underscore) in vim?

Tags: vim, key-bindings

I want my vim command `x` to delete a character but not copy it to a register.

Through googling, I found that `"_x` does the trick, but if I try to remap to `x`, whenever I press `x` my vim freezes. I'm using:

`nmap x "_x`

I tried various other things as well, but none seemed to work and I cannot find any information on why this wouldn't work with underscore

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`:nnoremap x "_x`

When you make that mapping, it contains the character you're remapping, which makes it what is called a "recursive" mapping.  All that means is that it tries to run itself over and over and over, and never quits (because it never actually encounters an error condition).  To make a mapping and tell it "don't be recursive - any characters in the value of this mapping should have their native, base meanings in vim -- not whatever I might have mapped them to", you just prepend 'nore' to the map command (but after the mode specifier), as shown above.